# Java - Correct Object Slicing in Vector<>

Tags: java, object, vector, slice

The following code works, but I get a compiler warning "raw use of parametrized class 'Vecor'".
So java allows object slicing but gives still a compiler warning? Are there more elegant solutions?

```
public class Derived extends Base {}

Vector<Derived> getVectorOfDerived();
Vector<Base> getVectorOfgetBase();

...
Vector<Base> v = DO_TEST ? (Vector<Base>) (Vector) getVectorOfDerived() : getVectorOfgetBase();
```

Background: This is one of the few cases where object slicing seems to make sense to me:
"Derived" are test-data which is specialized from production-data "Base".
"Derived" has the same behavioral *features* (variables, functions) like "Base",
but *behaves* different. To put all test-stuff in the "Base" class would make the code confusing.

EDIT:
Thx, Vector<? extends Base> compiles without errors, but I have many functions f(Vector v). These cannot be called that way anymore. The old cast (Vector< Base>) (Vector) works. Java defines "public class Vector< E>", so at this point the class is obviously explicitly defined. Maybe the intended way would be to switch to a function like public synchronized boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)?

```
class Base{}
class Derived extends Base{}
...

void f1(Base b) {}
void f2(Vector<Base> v) {}
...

Derived d = ...
Vector<Derived> vd = ...
Vector<? extends Base> vdb = ...
f1(d); // ok
f2(vd) // error 
f2(vdb) // error 
f2((Vector<Base>) vdb); // ok, but wrong hint "Cast may be removed..."
f2(vd); // error
f2((Vector<Base>)vd); //error
f2((Vector<Base>)(Vector)vd); // Warning "Raw use of parameterized Class Vector"

// solution? Too awkward:
vb.addAll(vd); // ok
f2(vb);
```

Comment: Why are you casting at all?  If the functions are returning the correct generic, there's no reason cast. Also, it's generally bad form to use implementation classes for variable types. You should have something like:
List<Derived> getDerived();
List<Base> getBase();

List<Base> list = DO_TEST ? getDerived() : getBase();

Answer (score 1):

Try to define `v` like this:

```
Vector<? extends Base> v = DO_TEST ? getVectorOfDerived() : getVectorOfgetBase();
```

Here `v` will be a vector of `Base` objects or objects inherited from `Base` (e.g. `Derived`).

Answer (score 1):

Declare f2 as following, then remove all casts.

```
void f2(Vector<? extends Base> v) {}
```